# Is it (easily) possible by a Linux application yo kill the kernel or crash the init process

Tags: linux, kernel, init

I am running into problems with an embedded Linux environment. Try to determine whether it can be caused by the application. How easy is it for an application to cause a kernel crash/lockup or kill init ?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be impossible for a non-root application to affect either one.

An application running as root has many possible ways to crash the kernel. It could try to load a module that is not supported by the hardware. It could write directly to IO ports. It could change the memory map or rewrite PCI bus entries (or whatever bus your embedded device uses).

This is yet another good reason to not run applications as root.